# Python splitting value error

Tags: python

I have problems with python split() function. Can someone help me to fix this error which splits the elements of dictionary and returns it line by line:

```
def lines_to_dict(lines):
    return_dict = {}
    for ll in lines:

            [key, value] = ll.split()
            return_dict[key] = value

    return return_dict
```

when i run

```
 lines = ["the :1", "and :2"]
    print (lines_to_dict(lines))
```

gives me `{"the": ":1", "and": ":2"}` in the same line. However I should get

```
the :1  
and :2
```

I tried using [key, value] = ll.split(',') but it gave me an error

```
    [key, value] = ll.split(",")
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

Comment: You are confused about what the problem is; your code creates a dictionary just fine, but you are complaining about the way Python *prints* dictionaries. You can't split on ',' because that's just part of the dictionary display, it's not in your text!

Answer (score 2):

Your function works just fine, it is returning a *dictionary* of parsed items. If you wanted to print those items on separate lines, you need to *loop* through the dictionary:

```
lines = ["the :1", "and :2"]
result = lines_to_dict(lines)
for key, value in result.items():
    print(key, value)
```

What you are seeing is the dictionary string representation:

```
>>> result
{'and': ':2', 'the': ':1'}
>>> result['and']
':2'
>>> for key, value in result.items():
...     print(key, value)
...
and :2
the :1
```